# Can I check if user email verification was successful using Django automated testing?

Tags: python, django, django-tests

My AccountActivationView expecting a GET request to path('email/confirm/', if the key exists, AccountActivationView invokes activation function and toggles is_active in user profile.
I'm trying to implement a test for this feature using Django TestCase, but it does not produce the results I'm expecting. The view class redirects Client to the right location, but is_active state of the user account does not change. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

```
class TestUserAccounts(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

        # Initial user data
        self.username = 'TestTest'
        self.email = 'test@test.com'
        self.password = 'test123test'

        # Creating user
        User.objects.create_user(
            email=self.email, username=self.username, password=self.password)

    def test_activating_user(self):
        '''Activating user account using link in the email'''

        user_email_activation_status = EmailActivation.objects.get(
            email=self.email).activated
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.email).is_active
        activation_key = EmailActivation.objects.get(
            email=self.email).key

        # The initial state of account and email should be inactive
        self.assertEqual(user_email_activation_status, False)
        self.assertEqual(user, False)

        # Activating the account with get request to email/confirm/<key>
        activation = self.client.get(
            reverse('accounts:email-activate', kwargs={'key': activation_key}))
        print(activation)

        # Checking if activation was successful
        self.assertEqual(user_email_activation_status, True)
        self.assertEqual(user, True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to rerun the query to check the status of user after you hit the URL to activate the user

```
class TestUserAccounts(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

        # Initial user data
        self.username = 'TestTest'
        self.email = 'test@test.com'
        self.password = 'test123test'

        # Creating user
        User.objects.create_user(
            email=self.email, username=self.username, password=self.password)

    def test_activating_user(self):
        '''Activating user account using link in the email'''
        activation_key = EmailActivation.objects.get(
            email=self.email).key
        user_email_activation_status = EmailActivation.objects.get(
            email=self.email).activated
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.email).is_active  
        # The initial state of account and email should be inactive
        self.assertEqual(user_email_activation_status, False)
        self.assertEqual(user, False)

        # Activating the account with get request to email/confirm/<key>
        activation = self.client.get(
            reverse('accounts:email-activate', kwargs={'key': activation_key}))
        print(activation)

        # Checking if activation was successful
        # get the value again after calling the route to activate the user
        user_email_activation_status = EmailActivation.objects.get(
            email=self.email).activated
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.email).is_active
        self.assertEqual(user_email_activation_status, True)
        self.assertEqual(user, True)
```

Comment: Can't believe I've spent half an hour trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I was certain the query hits database twice. Thank you, ashishmohite.